# UIScrollView does not show all contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

UIScrollView does not show all contents(especially, bottom's) as you can see below.[image: UIScrollbar not working]

I set the contentSize of UIScrollbar like that

```
- (void)readingRoomView:(HJHReadingRoomView *)view preferredSize:(CGSize)size
{
    self.scrollView.contentSize = size;
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
}
```

Why is it not working :'( ?

Comment: Given view which you would like to show in UIScrollView is HJReadingRoomView, I would try `self.scrollView.contentSize = view.bounds.size` also remove `view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);`

Comment: How and where you're calling this method? It seems that you're missing the 44px of the navbar.

Comment: HJHReadingRoomBar is my custom view, and I overrided drawRect method to draw

Comment: Have you tried `scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;`

Comment: @Mat when map data is received, my custom view calculate preferred size, and send it using delegate, `[self.delegate readingRoomView:self preferredSize:size];`

Comment: @Robert Now, scrollView shrinks the white area that must be shown as some drawings

Comment: oh.. sorry guys I think I miscalcualted my preferred size; No.. I calculated my preferred size correctly. :'(

Comment: @Mat I hard coded 44px to my frame size, and now it shows all my view correctly. Can you tell me why this is happened?

Comment: I think because the `view` frame is relative to the `window` coordinates, but it seems that the `scrollview` frame is relative to the navigation controller coordinate (so 44px down). You can hardcode the 44px of your navbar, but consider to do all in the same controller to avoid this type of problem when you use navigationcontrollers.